# Retrieve value of element on dom on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript function which is used to keep users from inundating our server with Ajax requests:

```
var validateZip = function () {

    var lastSuccessful = parseInt(jQuery('#mailingZip').val(), 10);

    return {
        validate: function(zip) {
            var is5DigitNumber = /^\d{5}$/;
            if (is5DigitNumber.test(zip) && lastSuccessful !== zip) {
                lastSuccessful = zip;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
}();
```

This page is reloaded if users input a bad zip code or other errors appear on the form.  However since the dom hasn't loaded yet, I always pull NaN from that field.

Placing it in the on document ready for jQuery means that I can't call the function directly.

How can I modify my scope such that the lastSuccessful will remain "private" and get the value once the dom is ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why I didn't think / do this before.  I created a getter/setter on my return function, then on the document ready just called the setter with that value.

var validateZip = function() {

```
// Track the last sent in zip code -- treat this as private data
var lastSuccessful = "";

return {
    validate : function(zip) {
        var is5DigitNumber = /^\d{5}$/;
        if (is5DigitNumber.test(zip) && lastSuccessful !== zip) {
            lastSuccessful = zip;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },

    setLastSuccessful : function(zip) {
        lastSuccessful = zip;
    },

    getLastSuccessful : function() {
        return lastSuccessful;
    }
}
```

}();

jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    validateZip.setLastSuccessful(jQuery('#mailingZip').val());
});

Answer (score 1):

```
function validateZip() { // use function declaration, not function expression

    var lastSuccessful = parseInt(jQuery('#mailingZip').val(), 10);

    return {
        validate: function(zip) {
            var is5DigitNumber = /^\d{5}$/;
            if (is5DigitNumber.test(zip) && lastSuccessful !== zip) {
                lastSuccessful = zip;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
}; // removed premature invocation of function

jQuery(validateZip); // call it on document ready instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you call it in  ready event? **Of course you can** enclose it into another function:

```
$(functon(){

    var validateZip = function () {

        var lastSuccessful = parseInt(jQuery('#mailingZip').val(), 10);

        return {
            validate: function(zip) {
                var is5DigitNumber = /^\d{5}$/;
                if (is5DigitNumber.test(zip) && lastSuccessful !== zip) {
                    lastSuccessful = zip;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }();

});
```

The question is you you need to keep `validateZip` function as defined global? If you only run it at this point, just omit its declaration and just write:

```
$(functon(){

    (function () {

        var lastSuccessful = parseInt(jQuery('#mailingZip').val(), 10);

        return {
            validate: function(zip) {
                var is5DigitNumber = /^\d{5}$/;
                if (is5DigitNumber.test(zip) && lastSuccessful !== zip) {
                    lastSuccessful = zip;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    })();

});
```

Comment: Yes, the validateZip function needs to remain global -- I need to be able to call validateZip.validate(userValue), as this is triggered on keyup, as the user inputs into the field the function will be called, when the user inputs 5 digits an Ajax call is made.  Let's say they submit the form and there is an error on another field, and this page is reloaded.  I want to get the value from the dom, and set that as lastSuccessful.  This way further calls are blocked if zip remains same.